# Segregating concurrently/non-concurrently accessible data members of a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class, let's call it `MainThread` which is going to be called through a non blocking main thread. Now this class has to perform some tasks which it delegates to a secondary class, let call it `AsycnThread`. Now `AsyncThread` actually does nothing but call some functions of class `MainThread`. This implies that there would be some members of `MainThread` could be accessed concurrently. Since I wanted to avoid any locks, I designed class `MainThread` in such a way that some of it's members can be accessed concurrently without any problem, while some are specifically off limits. One more details here, class `MainThread` has a specific function classed `performTask` which is called from `AsyncThread`.

Given the background, my goal is to make this code as maintainable as possible. Now in order to make this distinction of data members of `MainThread`, I made them mutable and the function `performTask const`. Now what this does is that if I try to access any data member that is not safe for concurrent use in `performTask`, compiler reports an error. Below is a skeleton structure of the class.

```
class MainThread {
public:
// Will be called asynchronously
void performTask() const;

private:
// Non concurrent data members
std::vector<int> data_store;
// Concurrently accessed data member
mutable CachedVec cache;
}
```

Does this seem like a good approach ? Are there any alternate approaches to achieve similar objective ?

Comment: I like this solution however it feels like it contradicts the real purpose of `const` method and `mutable` variable...

Comment: @AlexLop. Yes you are right. That's why I am a little apprehensive about using this method. I was hoping fellow developers could provide a more comprehensive way of why this approach is wrong.

Comment: I don't think it is a bad or really wrong approach it is just a little confusing. Is there an option to make `performTask()` global and all the `mutable` variables `public` or private but to make them accessible through a public accessor (set/get)?

Comment: It is confusing, because it doesn't follow the convention and intended use for constructs you are using. As a result, the code is likely to give a headache to any maintainer but you. Instead, I'd simply move away thread safe methods from the MainClass behemoth and declare MainClass single-thread only.

Answer (score -1):

1) volatile Member Functions 
2) LockingPtr template for mutex acquire/release functionality

Find more detail @ 
http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766